# How do I get a pass now?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Well, I messed up. The guards denied me entry at a gate on the road to Novigrad, telling me that I need some kind of pass to get through. I bribed the guard, and he told me that someone is selling passes. I talked to the shady merchant, and he told me I'd get one cheaper if I helped his brother-in-law.

I went to the brother-in-law, and tried to help with the monster problem. I managed to kill all the monsters, but it seems the brother-in-law died during the monster attack. The shady merchant didn't take these news very well and I can't get a pass from him now.

Where can I get a pass to enter Novigrad and Oxenfurt now?

Comment: I also failed that quest but somehow managed to get the 'pass' anyway. It was obviously (hilariously) a fake; I haven't been to Novigrad yet but I don't think I'll try using that pass when I do. You can get a pass from the Bloody Baron during the Family Matters quest anyway.

Comment: You can actually just swim into Oxenfurt, and nobody will bat an eye. Don't know if it's possible in Novigrad, though.

Answer (score 6):

There seem to be many ways to get passes - I probably don't know all of them. However, here are a few more:

- The Witcher Contract "Woodland Beast", starting by the Bridge to Novigrad has a potential reward of a pass, along with the cash
- Completing the "Family Matters" questline with the Baron still available should get you a pass

Comment: Yeah these work, I had the same issue, but after doing a few other quests, I got the pass and was able to proceed without issue.

Comment: The deadly plot one is not the same pass, since you've already entered Novigrad. The pass you get there is one stating you are not a mage. It is because of the thing you did to get the deadly plot quest.

Comment: This was by the guardpost far to the south, after receiving the "not-a-mage pass". Though based on timing, I'm inclined to agree. I'd be interested to confirm this one way or the other.

Comment: @Jeeva I don't think you can, because by the time that happens you've entered Novigrad already. Maybe by swimming or such you can skip the gates but I haven't tried it

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about trying to swim across next play.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a pass to enter the cities at all: just swim to the boat anchored on the side of the border camp, and take it (the archers will attack you so be fast), this will unlock the fast travel point inside the camp, port there, and jump over the closed gate to the other side... done
(the boat is optional, but i found it useful for escaping the archers, they are about level 35 or more)

also pursuing the quest Deadly Plot (gotten from Djikstra in novigrad) gets you a pass as well

Comment: Ah, that's cool news. You're certain it was a city pass?

Comment: for the city itself I wasn't asked right away for a pass.. i think that event is triggered somehow
anyhow It was taken care of immediately by a helpful npc, and I suppose that this happens always, but i am not certain